# How to translate the location service request dialog on iOS in a Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, localization, translation, location-services

I want to use the location service in a Flutter app with multiple languages. This all is no problem and works fine, except for the translation of the location service usage request in iOS. For some reason, whatever I try, the language used remains the base language (English). Not just the extra string that I give through the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription info.plist entry, but the complete dialog.

I have added the languages through the Project Runner > Info tab > Localizations

I have added the languages in the info.plist file Localizations key.

The above mentioned NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in the info.plist file is set.

I have separate InfoPlist.strings files for each language in the lproj directories with each an entry for the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key.

When I run the app (simulator or real device) I can change the language in the app settings as expected and the app changes language. All strings are translated as expected, but when I want to access the location service for the first time, the dialog to request permission remains in English. And I have checked with different strings, it uses the entry from the Base.lproj/InfoPlist.strings file. Why does it not recognize the correct language setting?

Edit after checking the comment below: the dialog changes language when the device language is changed (not the app). However, the app info string that is included remains the string from the base.lproj/InfoPlist.strings file, not the specific language string. How to change that as well?

Comment: The dialog is presented by iOS, not your app, so it will respect the language that is set for the whole device in settings

Comment: @Paulw11 Caramba... that's it indeed. When I change the device language it does translate the dialog. Thanks! However, it keeps using the base.lproj string, not the string relevant to the language that is used. So when I turn the device to Dutch, the dialog is in Dutch, but the extra info string is still in English (the base language). That part isn't solved yet...

Comment: @ehusmann have you solved extra info part?

Comment: @Guvanch, no I have not...

Comment: @ehusmann check the link on my answer

Comment: @Guvanch I am sorry, which link in which answer exactly?

Comment: @ehusmann https://zopagaduanjr.medium.com/customization-and-localization-of-permissions-in-flutter-f1968dab0943

Comment: @Guvanch I finally had the time to check it out. It seemed like I had taken all steps as mentioned in the article, but removed the previous files and strings and followed all steps to the t. Result: same as before. App base language is English with Dutch as secondary, phone set to language Dutch, region Netherlands, app set to Dutch. The dialog is all in Dutch, the app provided string remains in English. So no, I am sorry, it did not work either.